# Почему inline-block не выравнивается по vertical-align: middle?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Столкнулся с такой задачей: красный `inline-block` отчего-то не хочет выравниваться по центру контейнера `vertical-align: middle;` и выходит за его границы - почему и как это можно решить?

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}
.class-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.class-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.class-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class-1"></div><div class="class-2"></div><div class="class-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: vertical align вообще капризный чорт
извини, помочь мало чем могу, но вот тут описаные особенности использования его http://web-standards.ru/articles/vertical-align/
не пинай сильно, я от чистого сердца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решить можно добавив `vertical-align:middle` первому блоку.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
}
.class-1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
.class-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.class-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="class-1"></div><div class="class-2"></div><div class="class-3"></div>
</div>
```